# Alternate web.config for different servers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I was reading this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx but when I right click on web.config in Visual Studio the "Add Coding Transforms" is grayed out.  (I am not debugging or anything.)

Basically, I want to change my connection strings based on what server I'm publishing to.  I have a dev server, and I have a productions server.

What way can I accommodate this in ASP.NET MVC?

Currently, there exist two files under my web.config: `Web.Debug.Config` and `Web.Release.Config`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the [Solution Configuration dropdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166577%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and add a new configuration.

Note that you can have different compile constants, code contract settings, etc when you do this.  Be sure to copy an existing configuration (ie, Release).  Also, Code Contract settings DON'T currently copy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I can't find the Solution Configuration dropdown.  Do you know how I can get to it (I looked in the link you sent, too)?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it under the dropdown next to the "start debugging" button.  I have the same password and username for my connection strings, I just have to switch the server.  How can I do that, do you know?  Thanks.

Comment: @user1477388 In your transform you only include the changes, so you need a `<connectionStrings>` section and then `<add>` elements for only those you wish to change.  Unforutnately you need to include the entire element; So much of the string will be the same except for the user name and password.